# Bootstrap default numbers different size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This might sound really basic so excuse me for that. I have this table column
[image]

Text format just fine but some numbers are bigger some smaller. Is this some kind of font? Tried some fiddles for testing they had normal number formatting.
I use .card .card-body and .table classes for displaying this table

Comment: change your default font

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif yeah thanks, that was stupid.